# Calculate mean of sub arrays within a larger 3D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean

I have a 3D array like this:

```
 a = ([[[25,  4, 54], [58, 14, 27], [35, 40, 62], [53, 72, 86], [87,  4, 51], [89, 34, 22]],
       [[61, 99, 89], [52, 93, 18], [ 0, 38, 12], [99, 10, 98], [79, 91, 75], [31, 59,  3]],
       [[22,  9, 63], [37, 26,  3], [54, 40, 39], [36, 87, 44], [81, 10,  7], [75, 29, 20]],
       [[55, 30, 44], [21, 36, 98], [56, 52, 78], [80, 76, 32], [72, 26, 17], [15, 81, 37]],
       [[73, 37, 28], [30, 44, 75], [66, 59, 61], [34, 57, 56], [13, 51, 73], [20, 51, 94]],
       [[86, 38, 69], [85, 74, 91], [25, 90, 58], [50, 12, 79], [24, 96, 28], [73,  2, 17]]])
```

and I am trying to calculate the mean of 4 elements of each subsequent
row and column, subsequently, across the the entire matrix, in order
to have small squares mean samples of the large matrix. I expect to
have a resulting integer matrix like:

```
 ([[[49, 52, 47], [47, 40, 64],
```

... and so on...

I tried using the slicing with step followed by the mean function like

```
a[::2].mean()
```

but it does not return the result I expect.

So far what I can get is the mean of a column or row using the

```
numpy.mean(a, axis=0 or 1)
```

but this is not useful to me because it returns the entire column or
row mean and not means of 4 elements across the matrix.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps provide a smaller input and exact expected output as the explanation doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: where do `[49, 52, 47]` come from?

Comment: Sorry...[49,52,47] come from the calculated mean of the first 2 elements of the row and the first 2 elements of the collumn. i.e. ([[[25,  4, 54],[58, 14, 27], [[61, 99, 89],[52, 93, 18],    - But being simpler if I have a matrix like: g=[[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6]]] I would like to calculate the mean of [[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[[4,5,6],[4,5,6]] and again the mean of [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[[4,5,6],[4,5,6]]. The expected result would be: [[[2.5, 3.5, 4.5]],[[2.5, 3.5, 4.5]]]. But since I want integers it would be: [[2, 3, 4],[2, 3, 4]].

Comment: That's not a very good example in your comment, because of the repeated numbers. Also, it doesn't really clarify what should happen with "rows" beyond the first two: should it take row 1 + row 2, then row2+row3 and so on? Suggestion: create an example with either letters or with completely different numbers for an array of shape. Or clarify why Carsten's answer isn't correct yet?

Comment: Sorry I´m newbie with Python. I´m switching from Octave where matrices are displayed in a different way. So I´m still a bit confused about the way Python deals with matrices. But Carsten just got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to calculate the mean value of entries (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1), then of (2,2), (2,3), (3,2), (3,3), and so on.

You select every second column and row, four times, starting with indices (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1), respectively. Then, you divide by 4 and round the result:

```
np.round((a[::2,::2] + a[1::2,::2] + a[::2,1::2] + a[1::2,1::2]) / 4.0)
```

This gives you

```
array([[[ 49.,  52.,  47.],
        [ 47.,  40.,  64.],
        [ 72.,  47.,  38.]],

       [[ 34.,  25.,  52.],
        [ 56.,  64.,  48.],
        [ 61.,  36.,  20.]],

       [[ 68.,  48.,  66.],
        [ 44.,  54.,  64.],
        [ 32.,  50.,  53.]]])
```

Comment: Carsten, your answer is perfect! However, I´m facing a problem due to the nature of my matrix (RGB). The problem occurs when the sum of values is higher than 255, resulting in a lower number. For ex.: x=([[[255,   8, 54], [165, 69, 21],[63, 166, 49],[32,170,118],[39, 90,171],[80,60,220]],[[255, 8, 54],[165, 69, 21],[63,166,49],[32,170,118],[39,90,171],[80,60,220]]], dtype=uint8) is returning as: ([[[18., 38., 38.],[48., 40., 20.],[60., 11., 4.]]]) when it should be: ([[[210,38,38],[48,168,84],[59,75,196]]]). Should I change the matrix type before I apply the function you suggested?

Comment: @Fern Exactly. The data type of your array is `uint8` (a byte) and therefore cannot hold values greater than 255. Use [something like `b = a.astype(int)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) first to convert the array, then my solution will work properly.

Comment: Yes, it worked fine @Carsten. Thank you! Unfortunaly I can´t upvote your answers because I´m new in the list.